# install JUnit eclipse ubuntu 10.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, junit, tdd

I need to use JUnit in Eclipse (Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers; Version: Kepler Service Release 1; Build id: 20130919-0819) environment on Ubuntu 10.04 OS for a core Java project adopting TDD technique. I have Eclipse installed in Ubuntu 10.04 machine, but JUnit is not there. I tried to install with the following 2 methods:

Launch Eclipse > "Help" > "Check for Updates". But there are no JUnit plug-in tool test of anything related to JUnit at all. (Source : http://www.javaboardtest.com/gettingstarted.htm)

In a different approach which says start eclipse with root user, I could not find write command to run eclipse from terminal. I am not sure from what source/how the eclipse is installed (Source : http://codespin.blogspot.in/2008/01/enabling-junit-testing-in-eclipse-for.html).

When I try to run Eclipse in the terminal I get the following error:

```
$ sudo eclipse
sudo: eclipse: command not found

$ eclipse
The program 'eclipse' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform
```

And I don't have javac installed and want to use Eclipse alone for JUnit.

pls guide me to get through this (may be with some useful link). thanks..

Comment: So what happens when you type ```sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform```?

Comment: First:  **never run any IDE as super user.**  Second:  you should read the installation instructions from Eclipse on how to install their IDE.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "JUnit is not there"? Where are you expecting to see it, but not seeing it? In the Build Path project setting dialog, if you hit Add Library, do you see JUnit there?

Comment: I have Eclipse installed, but I need JUnit plug-in to work with @JonSkeet.

Comment: How are you determining that it *isn't* there? In the list of plugins, have you checked under "Java Development Tools"? Are you able to add a JUnit library? Which version of Eclipse are you using anyway? Bear in mind that referring to a 6-year-old article (your second link) is not terribly useful unless you're also using a 6-year-old version of Eclipse.

Comment: Version: Kepler Service Release 1;
Build id: 20130919-0819 @JonSkeet

Comment: @CanadianDavid the eclipse is already installed. the thing is I can't install JUnit in it.

Comment: And for the third time... In an existing Java project, in the Build Path configuration, under Add Library, is JUnit mentioned?

Comment: @JonSkeet no. Its not mentioned..

Comment: @Mithun: Right, finally. And under Help > Install New Software... have you tried that?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, but how to give url/xml file for JUnit.

Comment: It should just be in the Kepler software site (just look at what sites are automatically configured for you).

Comment: @JonSkeet; when I tried using Install New Software, I could not browse for JUnit in the sub category "Testing". There I can find only "Jubula Function Testing", "Jubula Launch Support for Eclipse RCP" and "Jubula Launch Support for Java / Swings". Is it any ware related to JUnit. And I have browsed through all category as well, but no use.

Comment: I'd expect it to quite possibly be under "Eclipse Java Development Tools" as it's such a base part of Eclipse Java tooling. I'm afraid at this point I don't think I can really help any more - this is too long for an SO comment thread anyway, to be honest.